# vb.net datagridview set selected cell after CellEndEdit

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a column in my dgview which must only contain double values, I put the code in the **CellEndEdit** event. If the value entered isn't a double the cell will be selected and begin edit

```
 Dim flag_cell_edited As Boolean
 Dim currentRow As Integer
 Dim currentColumn As Integer

 flag_cell_edited = True
 currentColumn = e.ColumnIndex
 currentRow = e.RowIndex


 If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If Double.TryParse(dgView.CurrentCell.Value, Nothing) Then

        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Value")
            'dgView.CurrentCell = dgItems(currentColumn, currentRow)  'Does not select the cell
            '------------------
            'This next 3 lines of code works for selecting the cell and beginning
            'Edit but when I type, it appears on the cell the was focused after editing

            'dgView.Rows(currentRow).Cells(currentColumn).Selected = True
            'dgView.Rows(currentRow).Cells(currentColumn).Value = vbNullString
            'dgView.BeginEdit(True)


        End If
 End If
```

That's what I have, if i edited `Rows(0).Cells(2)` with a value that isn't double then click on say `Rows(1).Cells(0)` it returns the selection to `Rows(0).Cells(2)`, removes the value then begins edit. When I type something, it appears on `Rows(1).Cells(0)` instead of `Rows(0).Cells(2)`

Comment: You need to handle the [DataGridView.CellValidating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thank you, i've done what I wanted